# "Privacy Breach" in Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the official expression in Esperanto for "Privacy Beach"?

If not "the official", perhaps "the best" or "the most recognized".

I am having troubles with this one. There are many ways, yet, I'm not sure how to peg this one correctly.

Some expressions/verbs I could find about it:

- rompi
- malrespekti
- malobservi
- perfidi
- malobei

But--maybe it is my failure--I haven't been able to find the authoritative expression.

To give more context, I want to translate this article in Esperanto:

https://www.priv.gc.ca/en/blog/20191031/

Your insight will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Komputeko.net gives you [*malkonfidencigo*](https://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=Privacy) for "privacy compromise". You have to decipher that word a little.

   - [*konfidenco*](http://vortaro.net/#konfidenci) : confidence
   - *-ig* : to make someone/-thing to have confidence
   - *-igo* : the act of making someone/-thing to have confidence
   - *mal-…-igo* : the act of making someone/-thing to not have confidence

You have to remember that such Esperanto words with multiple pre- and postfixes often carry a meaning, that is not necessary obvious from the parts by themselves. Unfortunately Komputeko doesn't give the source for *malkonfidencigo*.

2. Reta vortaro gives *breĉo* for "breach", so "privacy breach" could be translated to "privateca breĉo" or "breĉo pri privateco" or "privatecobreĉo".

To summarise I would choose the term listed in Komputeko, even if it's a bit hard-to-decipher, but in such a text you should define anyway what is understood by a privacy breach. In any case do not translate "compromise" to *kompromiso*.

Comment: Interesting. Reading your comment, here is how I think I will begin the article: "La kanada Ofico pri Privateca Komisaro ricevis 680 deklarojn pri malkonfidencigo aŭ „privateca breĉo”..." and in the rest of the article, I will just use „breĉo” to keep the text lighter. I think this resolves my inquiry. Thanks!

Comment: Such a stipulative definition is the recommended way, and your approach sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox the translation for breach is `datumfuĝo` ([full list](https://transvision.mozfr.org/?recherche=breach&repo=gecko_strings&sourcelocale=en-US&locale=eo&search_type=strings)).

So, `privateca datumfuĝo` could be a translation.

I find it interesting that [so many other language teams](https://transvision.mozfr.org/string/?entity=browser/browser/protections.ftl:monitor-title&repo=gecko_strings) also go for the data leak instead of the breach itself when they need to translate it. Some of those translations mean roughly `data leak`, some `data violation` or `data giveaway`.

That is to say that a better translation for `privacy breach` might well be related to the lost private data, as in `privateca datumfuĝo` or `privateca datumperdo / datumfordono`.

A more general way of describing it, if data is not strictly associated with the breach (say, a hole in an outdoor privacy wall), could be something like *[elmeto](http://vortaro.net/#elmeti) de privateco*. Anyway, nowadays privacy breach and data breach are used almost interchangeably and, [according to Symantec](https://us.norton.com/internetsecurity-privacy-what-is-a-privacy-breach.html), it should be so.

Comment: I think, that the referred article covers both cases, when data has leaked out and when someone has broken into the system. To my understanding this is covered by the term "privacy compromise", which Komputeko translates to _malkonfidencigo_. At least to me _perdo_ gets associated only with the leak. Don't know about _fuĝo_.

Comment: Though a data breach can result in a violation of privacy, I am not sure we want "privacy breach" to be translated into an expression so thighly related to "data". Most privacy breaches don't even originate from a data leak. For instance, if you share some personal information of yours to a trusted party for a specific purpose, but later that trusted party uses your information for a different purpose without  your consent, it is a privacy breach without data leak. -- Let's see if we find other expressions.

Comment: Data flowing through a non-authorized channel is still a data breach. That would include the case @mmorelfmc mentioned. But it's true that some breaches do not need to involve data, a hole in a perimeter wall could also be a privacy breach. I updated the answer to add a more general way to say it.

Answer (score 0):

La respondantoj tre klopodis formuli difinon de *privacy breach*, kio ne estas tasko de tradukanto. La Kanada leĝo (verŝajne tute intence) ne tiom precizigas la aferon ("breaches of security safeguards involving personal information").

La Esperanta vorto *breĉo* signifas ian truon aŭ fendon, kaj estas iom tro konkreta por ĉi tia leĝa signifo de "breach". Ne nepre okazas forfuĝo de datumoj tra truo, rompitaĵo aŭ alia liko en komputa sistemo. Mi elektus la simplan vorton *rompo*, kiu havas sufiĉe vastan signifon. Oni povas rompi leĝon, kontrakton, la Fundamenton de Esperanto, sian promeson, kaj certe ankaŭ ies privatecon.

Kontraŭ eventuala uzo de *kompromiso* jam prave atentigis Juha Metsäkallas. Se uzi ian similan vorton, la ĝusta elekto estus la verbo *kompromiti*, kiun oni iam vidas ankaŭ en simila senco, ekzemple: "Per tiu ĉi retejo vi povas kontroli ĉu viaj datumoj estis kompromititaj." Sed mi opinias, ke tia vorto ne estas bezonata ĉi tie.

Vi prezentis la konkretan frazon:

"La kanada Oficejo pri Privateca Komisaro ricevis 680 deklarojn pri malkonfidencigo aŭ „privateca breĉo”.

Mi iom reformulus ĝin:

*La Oficejo de la Kanada Komisaro pri Privateco ricevis 680 raportojn pri rompo de privateco.*

aŭ pli simple:

*La Kanada Komisarejo pri Privateco ricevis 680 raportojn pri rompo de privateco.*

aŭ, kial ne,

*La Kanada Komisaro pri Privateco ricevis 680 raportojn pri rompo de privateco.*

Estas ja memkompreneble, ke la raportoj estis senditaj al la *oficejo* de la aŭtoritato.